# Remove Extra Whitespace from Overflow Image CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the overflow of an image appear to be hidden upon a certain screen size, but I cannot find the solution of why this extra spacing appears. Here is the html an css I have so far. I am trying to do this because the image would appear too small.

Bootstrap solutions are also welcome too.

```css
.aboutsplash img{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 769px){
 .aboutsplash img{
 overflow: hidden;
 width: auto;
 max-height: 150px;  
 }
}
@media (max-width: 500px){
 .aboutsplash img{
 position: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 -25%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutsplash">
    <img src="images\sunsetcrop2.jpg" alt="lbl sunset">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @media (max-width: 769px){
    .aboutsplash {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
```

try this.

Comment: Before add this code, You should declare the width of .aboutsplach .

Comment: @user7644509 It's my pleasure.